# How do to keep the text on the same line. not letting him jump down

Tags: android

My EditText jumps when arrives at the end of the line. but I want it to continue on the same line.

what I might add for that this does not happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

to your XML

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, it's also possible to do that programmatically:

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
mEditText.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: hi mauker contact me please for alemaob7@gmail.com

Comment: What's the matter?

Comment: I want that User be obliged to enter in the field

Comment: Yes. I have an image button that is in the action bar , he's not checking

'public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (cnpj.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            cnpj.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_cnpj_required));'

Comment: I believe it's better to create another question for that. It's out of scope.